# Transformation that f(A+B)=f(A)+f(B) and f(AB) = f(A)f(B)

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation, linear-transformations

if $f:M_{n*n}(F) \rightarrow M_{m*m}(F) $ and f transformation identity to identity matrix and $f(AB) = f(A)f(B)  , f(A+B)=f(A)+f(B)$. now we want to prove there is an integer like $k$ that $m = k*n$

Comment: This question is not stated as we like it on math.stackexchange. Please provide us some context. What are your thoughts? (e.g. what have you already thought of but maybe didn't work out for you or you didn't figure how to let it work out) What have you tried? ...

Comment: @Dietrich Burde yes it's that what question means.

Comment: the relation I think it's because of
f(AB)=f(A)f(B)
f(A+B)=f(A)+f(B)